# Check if a value exists then capture another object's value

Tags: c#, json.net, nunit

I have a JSON response body like below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "mentor_id": 5,
    "mentee_id": [
      141,
      184
    ],
    "status": "Active",
    "session_count": 0,
    "current_job": null,
    "email": null,
    "phone_call": null,
    "video_call": null,
    "face_to_face": null,
    "created_at": "2020- 02 - 20 20: 37: 50",
    "updated_at": "2020- 02 - 20 20: 37: 50"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "mentor_id": 8,
    "mentee_id": [
      184,
      185,
      186
    ],
    "status": null,
    "session_count": 0,
    "current_job": null,
    "email": null,
    "phone_call": null,
    "video_call": null,
    "face_to_face": null,
    "created_at": "2020- 02 - 21 22: 39: 31",
    "updated_at": "2020- 02 - 21 22: 39: 31"
  }
]
```

Now I want to check if the  `"status"` contains **"Active"**. Then I need to return the first value from `mentee_id`.

How do I achieve this in C#? (I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON and NUnit)

Comment: for this json, you could deserialize it to array of object that match the Json. Use Linq to check if any object contains Active and get the first element from the array mentee_id.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class to capture the `Mentor` items:

```
class Mentor
{
    [JsonProperty("mentor_id")]
    public int MentorId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mentee_id")]
    public List<int> MenteeIds { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    // Add any other properties you might need in the same way
    // If you don't need a particular property you can safely omit it
}
```

Deserialize the JSON like this:

```
List<Mentor> mentors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mentor>>(json);
```

Then you can query like this:

```
Mentor firstActiveMentor = mentors.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Status == "Active");
if (firstActiveMentor != null)
{
    int firstMenteeId = firstActiveMentor.MenteeIds.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p7AnPv